# how to add extra field in 'order_item' table when product order success?

Tags: magento2, sales-order

Which event I have to use?
I have need to store product wise shipping tax.

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding I think you have to use Magento extension attribute feature

If you want to learn how to use Magento Extension attribute then I think you can go through with this link :

https://store.fooman.co.nz/blog/an-introduction-to-extension-attributes.html

In your case in extension_attribute.xml of your module you have to add code like this, this is the sample of gift_message column at order item level

```
<extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemInterface">
<attribute code="gift_message" type="Magento\GiftMessage\Api\Data\MessageInterface" />
</extension_attributes>
```

Comment: Use of `Magento extension attribute` is best idea.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to create an extra field on `sales_order_item` as magento already have tax fields to this table.

[image]

Comment: no i have add shipping tax not only tax

Comment: did you able to  create custom field?

Comment: no i see it first time

Comment: please donot called me sir...

Comment: i have done it..

Answer (score 0):

Magento already offers the tax field in it's table. Hence, I don't think you need to create an extra field. However, I can help you out if you can be a bit specific about what you wanna add.