# Magento 2 save product custom attribute in order to retrive them on sales information and otder email

Tags: magento2, sales-order, custom-attributes, order-email, order-grid

I have created a custom attribute that shows on the product detail page like colour and size attribute, I want them to be saved on order placement so that I can retrieve them in the order information, order email.

I am not sure how to achieve this, Right now I am displaying the custom attribute of the product in order but the value changes when I change the value in the product backend, I must show the value which is saved during order placement.

Comment: Are you saving that custom attribute value to order item (sales_order_item) table? if yes, then you can get that easily wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you have to follow the below sub-task to achieve this

1. Create a custom module
2. Add an [extension attribute](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/attributes.html#extension) that contains your custom attribute
3. Create an observer/plugin class and save the product attribute's value while place order event will trigger

You can also add just a new table column to the `sales_order_item` table instead of creating an extension attribute. But note that using an extension attribute is the better way from a maintainability and compatibility standpoint as you do not modify a Magento core table.

The below links will help you.

[You can follow the below tutorial to create a new module](https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/create-a-new-module/)

[how to add extra field in 'order_item' table when product order success?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/242199/how-to-add-extra-field-in-order-item-table-when-product-order-success)

Comment: Thank you is there a blog containing example